# Probes returning zero

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I've been struggling to understand why some HTTP endpoints return '0' for 'probe_success' and 'probe_http_status_code', while being perfectly able to get a "valid" response with curl.

Example: `curl -s "localhost:9115/probe?target=http://linux.org&module=http_2xx" | grep -v '^#'`

Output:

```
probe_dns_lookup_time_seconds 0.003712821
probe_duration_seconds 0.212811871
probe_failed_due_to_regex 0
probe_http_content_length 0
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="connect"} 0.002263513
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="processing"} 0.196389853
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="resolve"} 0.006723945
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="tls"} 0
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="transfer"} 2.6001e-05
probe_http_redirects 1
probe_http_ssl 0
probe_http_status_code 0
probe_http_version 0
probe_ip_protocol 4
probe_success 0
```

Here is the job definition:

```
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    scrape_interval: 30s
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - http://linux.org
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '(.*)(:80)?'
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        regex: '(.*)'
        target_label: instance
        replacement: '${1}'
      - source_labels: []
        regex: '.*'
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: 'blackbox:9115'
```

and the module definition:

```
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 15s
    http:
      valid_status_codes: []
      method: GET
```

Comment: Anything in the blackbox exporter logs? Where/how do you run the blackbo exporter? in a docker container? did you update/install the `ca-certificates` package?

Comment: @Oliver nothing on the blackbox-exporter logs. This is running on docker. Yes, I also installed ca-certificates under /etc/ssl/certs but the result is the same.

Comment: It would seem like you're getting one redirect (as per `probe_http_redirects 1`, likely to `https://linux.org`) but then that request fails. The `probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="tls"} 0` seems to support that. The short `probe_duration_seconds` suggests that HTTPS connection is not even attempted (for me it takes about 1+ seconds to get a successful probe). Firewall?

Comment: Did you try the `curl` request from within the blackbox_exporter container? (using docker exec ... /bin/sh)

Comment: @Oliver yes, I did.

Comment: Maybe we're all missing something obvious, but at first sight this seems to be a blackbox exporter bug. You should probably file an issue: https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/issues

Comment: sorry guys! I had 2 blackbox instances running and was testing against the wrong one... Nonetheless I have another couple of domains which are failing with the same output as above. I'll let you know as soon as I figure out why. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you append `&debug=true` you'll get some details on the error.

My **guess** is blackbox_exporter cannot connect because it defaults to ipv6 connections and that's not working.

In my case (same problem), the debug output says

```
level=error msg="Resolving target address" ip_protocol=ip6
level=error msg="Resolution with IP protocol failed (fallback_ip_protocol is false): err"
level=error msg="Error resolving address" err="address apple.com: no suitable address found"
level=error msg="Probe failed" duration_seconds=0.003648031
```

From the [blackbox documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md):

```
  # The IP protocol of the HTTP probe (ip4, ip6).
  [ preferred_ip_protocol: <string> | default = "ip6" ]
  [ ip_protocol_fallback: <boolean> | default = true ]
```

So, if you modify your module configuration and restart blackbox exporter, it should work:

```
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 15s
    http:
      valid_status_codes: []
      method: GET
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4" # <---- !
```

Comment: + for ` &debug=true `

Comment: But if ip_protocol_fallback is true per default, shouldn't it just fallback to ipv4 in case of an ipv6 error?

Comment: @Tim good point! I guess it should...`¯\_(ツ)_/¯` I now see that in my error log it said `fallback_ip_protocol is false`. I have no idea why my fallback was set to `false`; I guess if it's properly set to `true` it will simply fallback to ipv4 as you said.

Answer (score 5):

[Blackbox_exporter](http://kubefront.com/linux/how-to-install-and-configure-blackbox-exporter-for-prometheus) fetching endpoints routinely and provides crucial matrices regarding performance.

I have faced a similar issue. For me issue was typing error. But if you follow these simple debugging steps you can find your issue. right.

1. `curl -s "localhost:9115/probe?target=http://linux.org&module=http_2xx&debug=true"` for getting logs data
   [blackbox logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIOYE.png)
2. for me iptables rules not allowing

Answer (score 4):

In my error was: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Change option in http section

```
 tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: I think you should set `insecure_skip_verify` to `true`, NOT `false`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was to add in the `valid_http_versions` section the `HTTP/1.0` entry. My endpoint was Odoo 13. The `&debug=true` suggested by @Rafa got me the information to realize that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I specified an invalid http version (HTTP 1.1, but a response from a URL was HTTP 1.0).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yep this happened to me too, even the site status code is `200` the `probe_sucess` is `0` and within grafana it shows down as you can see in the image below:

[image: grafana shows status DOWN of a web site using Blackbox exporter]

In order to debug for the problem, you will have to run the following command:

```
curl -s "localhost:9115/probe?target=https://p******.****.com/_health&module=http_prometheus&debug=true" | grep "level=error"
```

with replacing `localhost:9115` with your **BlackBox Exporter Host** and **Port**, replace also the `target` link, and your module name `module=http_prometheus` which you will find it in your `blackbox.yml` config file, note the separator is `&`

by running the provided command, you will get all the possible errors that cause your `probe_sucess` to be `DOWN`, in my case I got :

```
ts=2024-01-09T16:01:52.30210574Z caller=handler.go:120 module=http_prometheus target=https://p******.****.com/_health level=error msg="Invalid HTTP version number" version=HTTP/2.0
ts=2024-01-09T16:01:52.302259439Z caller=main.go:181 module=http_prometheus target=https://p******.****.com/_health level=error msg="Probe failed" duration_seconds=0.045784811
```

so the error that I got is `msg="Invalid HTTP version number" version=HTTP/2.0`

with a simple search in google, I found that I have to add `HTTP/2.0` in the `valid_http_versions` within `BlackBox config file`

this is my config now after adding the new version:

```yaml
modules:
  http_prometheus:
    prober: http
    timeout: 5s
    http:
      method: GET
      valid_http_versions: ["HTTP/1.1", "HTTP/2", "HTTP/2.0"]  # << I added only "HTTP/2.0" for some reason "HTTP/2" wasn't working
      fail_if_ssl: false
      fail_if_not_ssl: false
```

then restart your `BlackBox exporter service`, and by running the same command you will notice that the previous error has vanished.

after a while you will see also in grafana that website status changed from `DOWN` to `UP` :D

[image: Website status is UP within Grafana with BlackBox Exporter]